# Is it possible to find arbitrary chars in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

My file looks like this:

```
Recipe: Trigger
Ingredients
{
    Electronics: 2
    Wood: 1
    Iron: 3
}

Recipe: Console
Ingredients
{
    Electronics: 8
    Glas: 5
    Iron: 6
}
```

and so on.

What i need is, that every `Electronics`-Amount gets multiplied by 10.

So that my file looks like this:

```
Recipe: Trigger
Ingredients
{
    Electronics: 20
    Wood: 1
    Iron: 3
}

Recipe: Console
Ingredients
{
    Electronics: 80
    Glas: 5
    Iron: 6
}
```

My Question: Is it possible to do this with the Replace function?

For this i have to ignore the amount and add a `0` after it.

Something like:

> Find all: "Electronics: *"
>
> Replace with: "Electronics: *0"

where * would be the char it should ignore.

This way it worked for me:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's possible

Comment: @HaBom and how can i do that? Your comment isn't very helpful yet...

Comment: Sorry I forgot the link

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\bElectronics:\h+\d+\K`
- Replace with: `0`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b              # word boundary
Electronics:    # literally
\h+             # 1 or more horizontal spaces
\d+             # 1 or more digits
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Recipe: Trigger
Ingredients
{
    Electronics: 20
    Wood: 1
    Iron: 3
}

Recipe: Console
Ingredients
{
    Electronics: 80
    Glas: 5
    Iron: 6
}
```

Comment: @AlpakaJoe: **Caution** this will work for integers only, not float.

Answer (score 0):

Tick on the `Wrap around` and `Regular Expression`. Then try this out

```
Find what   : ^(    Electronics: \d)
Replace with: \10
```

Comment: i tried that, but it tells me "Replace All: 0 occurrences were replaced."

Comment: Did you put the cirsor to the top of the text file, so every line is searched through?

Comment: yes. i tried it without the ^ - char and then it finds them correctly, but now the Replace with line is still wrong - it just replaces with "/10"?

Comment: yes the `^` means append. Oh I know why you got the error, check my edit answer.

Comment: i got it to work, i added a screenshot to my question. Thanks for your help!